# Spring MongoDb: pojo persistence configuration without annotation

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm using `spring-data-mongodb`, and I need to persist a third party class into my mongo database.

The problem is I'm not able to annotate those classes with `@Collection`, `@Id` annotations.

Is there any way to set the persistent behavior without using annotations?